# Visual Studio Code—Customizing word separators

Tags: editor, customization, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to customize (*i.e.*, in `settings.json`) the set of characters used to delimit words and tokens in Visual Studio Code? I'm referring to the set of characters used to control the behavior of actions like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, or double-clicks when navigating text.

Sublime Text supports a `"word_separators"` option for settings files that take a set of characters like `“./\()"’-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}~?”`. Does Code support a similar feature?

Comment: As far as I know word separators are managed per language in the language definition file. Take a look for example into your code installation folder in resources\app\plugins\vs.language.csharp\csharpDef.js there you will find the line that defines word separators for this language: "wordDefinition: /(-?\d*\.\d\w*)|([^\`\~\!\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\=\+\[\{\]\}\\\|\;\:\'\"\,\.\<\>\/\?\s]+)/g" - You could edit the definition for your language. But I'm not sure about the side effects. I think the separators are well defined by MS. Maybe you encountered a bug? What do you want to change exactly?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As of the February update, v0.10.10 (February 2016), **word navigation and word separators** has now been added!
As of today you can view the update announcement [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates#_editor) under "**Word navigation and word separators**", but after the next release the url will probably change to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/vFebruary#_editor)... I make this assumption based on previous releases.

Your settings file(s) now contain a section for editing **word navigation and word separators**

```
// Characters that will be used as word separators when doing word related navigations or operations
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
```

Comment: Helpful tip, you can also [override this setting on a per-language basis](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33701#issuecomment-469491567).

Comment: that is a helpful tip indeed mbomb007, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

To enable double click selecting the "$" symbol (for example) along with other text as well, you need to remove "$" symbol from delimiters.

**Settings** -> **Preferences** -> search "**editor.wordSeparators**" -> remove $ symbol
[image: Vs Code delimiters]

Adding this answer, because similar googling pointed me here. Hope comes useful to someone.

**Remark**: This was working **till 2020** I guess, than Microsoft changed something in Vscode and now you need to specify "**sepeterators-per-language**":

1. Open settings.json (ctrl+p settings.json)
2. add following line at the end of the file:

```
"[powershell]": {
            "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?",
        }
```

Just specify your language in [ ] and remove symbol you want to select with double click as well.