# Changing behavior of option+delete in vscode on mac

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Whenever I tried to delete a word on my mac in vscode using `option + delete` it deletes the word but stops as soon as it hits a non letter character.

Ideally I would like to delete every continuous sequence of characters until it reaches a space or period.

Current behavior:

`(If I just want to delete the last 'h1')`

> Cursor at the end of `<h1> </h1>`
>
> First deletes: `'>'`
>
> then `h1`
>
> Finally `</`

Desired behavior:

> Cursor at the end of `<h1> </h1>`
>
> Deletes in one go: `</h1>`

The default behavior is really slowing me down when I am coding. I've searched for answers but got [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104143/how-do-i-change-which-characters-os-x-considers-a-word-for-arrow-key-skippi), and it seems to be an old feature (2013) which is no longer available in high sierra.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632351/visual-studio-code-customizing-word-separators) and change your configuration accordingly.

It sounds like you'll want to remove <>\ as word delimiters.

From that article:

Your settings file(s) now contain a section for editing word navigation and word separators

`` // Characters that will be used as word separators when doing word related navigations or operations
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?", ``

Comment: @feoh While this did not change the behavior for deletion, your solution did change the default behavior for traversing and selecting text based on the delimiters that I wanted, which is great. Just not sure why it didn't do the same for deleting. Regardless, thank you!