# Navigate between words in two ways using different separators

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

Thanks to [Visual Studio Code—Customizing word separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632351/visual-studio-code-customizing-word-separators) I was able to set underscore as separator.
So now whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>, VS code recognizes that the word starts right after the underscore.
However sometimes I want go at the very beginning of the variable/function/class name and, using underscore as separator,  I have to press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> several times to get there.
Is there any way to get a behavior like:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> it considers underscore as separator
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> it doesn't consider underscore as separator

Comment: with extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#move-by) and command `moveby.regex` you can define a regex (wordchars) to search next/prev. You can define keybindings to call the command with arguments. By setting a `while` with the languageId you can set differences for languages

Comment: have you tried defining the keybindings yourself with the command `moveby.regex`

Comment: I don't get how that can help me, could you explain it more specifically, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).   Make this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+left",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
      "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
      "cursorLeft"    // just gets rid of the selection
    ]
  },
}
```

[image: move to start of while word]

Answer (score 1):

As rioV8 said, you can use the [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) plugin.

Follow these steps to get pretty much what you want:

1. Install the plugin from your Visual Studio Code Extensions tab (Ctrl+Shift+X)
2. Click on the bottom left gear and click on "Keyboard Shortcuts" as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LqvW.png)
3. At the top right corner of the "Keyboard Shortcuts" tab, you'll find three icons, click on the one at the left, [as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFEjQ.png) (or Ctrl+k Ctrl+s)
4. In the json file that has appeared on your screen, paste this:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+right",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.regex",
    "args": [
      "moveAvoidUnderscore",
      "moveby",
      "next",
      "end"
    ]
  }
```

Or at least insert this shortcut at the end of the file, following a ','.
[You should have something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQBpt.png).

5. In File > Preferences > Settings (Ctrl+,), search for `selectby`
6. Click `Edit in settings.json`
7. Replace anything you have with that:

```json
{
    "selectby.regexes": {
        "moveAvoidUnderscore": {
            "moveby": " "
        }
    }
}
```

8. To setup left: replace `"key": "ctrl+alt+left"` and `"args": [ ..., "prev", "start" ]`

If I didn't miss anything, you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way for achieving the desired behaviour is through the following steps:

1. **Exclude** `_` from the word separators in case you still have it included.
2. Add the two following `keybindings` to your `keybindings.json` :

   ```
    {      
       "key": "ctrl+shift+left",    
        "command": "cursorWordLeft",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    },

    {
        "key": "ctrl+left",
        "command": "cursorWordPartLeft",
        "when": "textInputFocus"
    }
   ```

The first keybinding allows you to move to the left of a word by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

The second keybinding allows you to move to the left of a word by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>  but considering `_` this time.