# Visual Studio Code - Customizing word part separators

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

In VS Code, you can define word separators with the setting `editor.wordSeparators` in `settings.json` (see an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632351/visual-studio-code-customizing-word-separators)). Later, you can use words and certain commands to define readline-like keyboard shortcuts. For example, you can bind `Ctrl+W` to `deleteWordLeft` in `keybindings.json` to delete the previous word as follows:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+w",
    "command": "deleteWordLeft"
}
```

Similarly to `deleteWordLeft` and `deleteWordRight`, there exist the commands `deleteWordPartLeft` and `deleteWordPartRight` which delete parts of words instead of full words (the readline equivalent would be `Alt+Backspace`). These commands suggest that there is a definition of "word part" somewhere in VS Code, which perhaps could be customized (potentially through a hypothetical setting `editor.wordPartSeparators`, but this setting doesn't exist as far as I can see).

Is there a way to customize the "word part" definition in VS Code?